# Split Strings into dynamic element names and values

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a string one of the nodes in my XML that is going to return a delimited list of values. Something similar to this string:

```
<Item>Code^ReturnCode|Description^ReturnDescription|System^ReturnSystem</Item>
```

What I am looking for is an output of

```
<Item>
  <Code>ReturnCode</Code> 
  <Description>ReturnDescription</Description> 
  <System>ReturnSystem</System>
<Item>
```

The element names and values are completely dynamic. I know I am getting close to the idea, but this is my first XSLT. Here is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:template match="/Container/Information" >
   <xsl:call-template name="splitReturn">
        <xsl:with-param name="String" select="text()"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="Separator" select="'|'"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="splitReturn">
    <xsl:param name="String"/>
    <xsl:param name="Separator"/>
    <xsl:element name="{substring-before($String,$Separator)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($String,$Separator)" />
    </xsl:element>  
</xsl:template>
```

I think I am just missing how to nest the templates that I am applying.

Answer (score 1):

You must make your template recursive. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="splitReturn"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template name="splitReturn">
    <xsl:param name="string" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($string, '|'), '|')" />    
    <xsl:if test="$token">
        <xsl:element name="{substring-before($token, '^')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($token, '^')" />
        </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($string, '|')">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="splitReturn">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '|')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to your input example:

```
<Item>Code^ReturnCode|Description^ReturnDescription|System^ReturnSystem</Item>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Item>
   <Code>ReturnCode</Code>
   <Description>ReturnDescription</Description>
   <System>ReturnSystem</System>
</Item>
```

Note that this will work only if the provided names are valid XML element names.